# Import using Django admin import-export throws error

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I am trying to import data through xls or JSON file. Django throws error while trying to import the file using the Django admin import-export functionality.

Following are the codes,

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Questions(models.Model):
    q_no_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    question = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def print_all(self):
        res = self.objects.all()
        for r in res:
            print(r.Question)
```

I have added `import_export` in the Installed_Apps section in the settings.py

**admin.py**

```
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Questions
from import_export import resources

class QuestionResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Questions
        fields = ('category', 'question')

@admin.register(Questions)
class QuestionAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass
```

The images for reference are as follows:
[image: Error]

The input xls file is as follows:

[image: Input xls file]

Why am I getting the error? I even tried removing the data from the q_no_id and created_at fields (as they are autofields) but still the error is persistent.

Comment: try removing last 3 lines in `admin.py`

Comment: I tried that it doesn't work. The last 3 lines are for getting the import export options in the django admin. If I removed them I am not even able to see the import export buttons which makes sense. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the foreign key for the import-export to look for. And you can override the standard `id` field as seen below:

```
class Meta:
        model = Questions
        import_id_fields = ('q_no_id',)
```